# Are questions about compiling/building third-party software off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've never been quite sure how to handle questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136236/compile-with-ubuntu-14-and-gcc-4-8) where the OP is apparently having difficulty building some piece of third-party software. I guess it's on-topic if the software in question is some sort of library that is subsequently going to be used as part of a software-development project, but what if it's just some generic piece of software that is throwing errors when the user tries to build it with their particular Linux distribution or [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) version and the user is not necessarily a programmer?

Clarification: although I gave one particular example above, this type of question is quite common, so I am looking for some general "rules of thumb" to apply, e.g. "if the OP is a programmer and is building something for development purposes then it's on-topic, otherwise off-topic."

Comment: Side note: consider if changing title to "...compiling..." would look better. I was puzzled when title showed up in "Hot Meta Post".

Comment: I see... Like your edit... and I really can't think of a word phrase that would means just "building tools from someone else sources" that would be short and at the same time excludes creating the tool yourself... (will remove this comments soon, wish self-expiring comments would exist).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most often OP has a big log of what happened when trying to build, and is totally lost. Solving his problem can't usually happen with a magical reusable answer but through an help exchange with an experienced user asking questions and analyzing answers until a diagnostic is made (or until it suddenly starts to work).

The usual problem with those questions isn't that they're off-topic, but that SO isn't tailored to handle them. This makes a choice that's not obvious. You should close the ones that clearly miss so much information and research that they'll obligatory end in an exchange of small questions and answers, answer when it's answerable, and probably let die the many in between that can only be answered per luck.

Comment: A lot of the time I'll find the answer to my question by looking at these one-off questions that were solved in a similar manner, or *pointed me in the right direction or a useful utility* in order to fix the problem myself. I have no problems with these questions.

Comment: @Qix I don't think they're useless either, I think SO isn't the right format.

Comment: @dystroy: So what is your rule of thumb on *what to do* with these questions? Just ignore them?

Comment: @Bergi I think it's like many things on StackOverflow: feel free to answer them if you think you can, but for many people it's just not the best use of their time. Otherwise ignore them, of if they aren't clear or well researched, downvote.

Comment: @RogerFan: Yes, that's my guess, but I thought this should be in the answer.

Comment: Questions like this will eventually be swept away by the Roomba, which is what should happen.  Having a bunch of unanswered questions about some obscure build error show up on Google searches just wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 17):

Among the things that are explicitly on-topic, as per the Help Center, is:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

gcc definitely applies; and the fact that gcc is ran on Ubuntu may be relevant to the question.

If a user has a problem with building a piece of software, but has shown that they have at least a basic understanding of what they are doing, the question is OK. If they don't have at least a basic understanding of what they're doing, a downvote may be in order. The subject matter is still on-topic (tools commonly used by programmers), but the question may be off-topic for other reasons - like "too broad", if it would take an entire tutorial to explain the user what is going on.

There are a few corner cases; for example, some editors are also often used by programmers, but if the question is about the usage of the editor itself, and is not actually related to programming, then the question is better off on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

If the actual usage of the tool is not about programming (where "programming" includes questions about compilers and linkers), then the question should be on Super User, assuming it is fit for Stack Exchange at all.

Comment: so to conclude this particular question is off-topic as there isn't any code involved in the question. An error message isn't enough... there are no expected results etc.

Comment: @vba4all It looks like everything needed to reproduce the problem is in there. Maybe the user should include a Makefile. I think that question can be salvaged.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - "can be salvaged" - that is exactly what "closed as off-topic/not enough info" is for - to give OP good chance to make it good SO question that have a chance to be useful for others.

Answer (score 8):

In answer to your question I believe these questions are acceptable and can be on topic.

However, every question is different so you have to be judicious when evaluating whether the question was written by someone with the minimal level of knowledge needed to be able to benefit from any answer you take the time to write.

I find the very first line of [What Questions Should I Ask Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is of great help to me in deciding whether I ought to bother to respond to a question asker:

> Stack Overflow is for **professional** and **enthusiast** programmers, people
>   who **write code because they love it**.

A professional or enthusiast programmer is seldom completely lost, and will usually have tried several different things to accomplish their aims and been able to narrow things down before crying for help.

The example you've linked to is not the sort of question I personally would expect a professional or enthusiast coder who writes code because they love it to have asked without supplying other information about what they had tried.

Comment: FFIW the OP of that question did provide more details in a comment. The lack of details in the original question is something I would put down to being new to the site.